# What is the chi regen (and shield) skill of Destroyers called?

Tags: blade-and-soul

I have noticed some destroyers grant a shield and decrease chi-regen time when party members are regenerating chi. What is this skill called, and how can I obtain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be [Iron Fortress](https://bnstree.com/DE?build=360000103011) that you're looking for, and it looks like it is gained at level 36.  It is activated by right clicking on a friendly target who is currently recovering Chi (instead of pressing <kbd>F</kbd>)

Here's a discussion, regarding it, as well:
https://www.reddit.com/r/bladeandsoul/comments/44t1gu/psa_for_destroyers/